# Hive How to create a table when using insert overwrite directory?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am wondering if it's possible to create(insert overwrite) a table when you are doing insert overwrite directory? The table should have the same data as stored in the directory. Right now I have something like:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY somepath
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
SELECT * FROM Table LIMIT 5;
```

I would like to have something like:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY somepath AND Table sometable
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE LIMIT 5;
```

Can someone suggest if it's possible. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to have data duplicated in some directory + table directory? Why not to create table on top of the same directory?

Comment: What's your objective?  Is it to reduce 2 statements into 1?  Like @leftjoin said, just create a table once pointing to that directory and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [multi-table insert](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries). Hive can insert into multiple tables and directories in single run. Multi Table Inserts minimize the number of data scans required. Hive can insert data into multiple tables/directories by scanning the input data just once (and applying different query operators) to the input data.

For example the statement below writes into table and into directory in a single statement (tested):

```
from 
(select 1 id, 'Santhosh' value union all
select 2 id, 'Rajesh' value union all
select 3 id, 'Valeriy' value )s

insert overwrite table test_1 select s.id, s.value

insert overwrite directory  'hdfs://your_dir/test_2' 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
select s.id, s.value;
```

You can also specify individual WHERE in each select.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify I can do something like: From someTable1                 
INSERT OVERWRITE someTable2 SELECT someTable1.field1 someTable1.field2                INSERT OVERWRITE someTable3 SELECT someTable1.field3 someTable1.field4 . Is this correct?

Comment: @Rockingchief Yes, just do it. Better use aliases instead of table name in selects. from someTable1 s1   INSERT OVERWRITE someTable2 SELECT s1.field1 s1.field2 ... and so on. Of course you can write multiple tables, mix them with multiple directories, for each select you can specify it's own WHERE clause.

Comment: @Rockingchief End even more: selects can be different also, with different columns, functions, etc